# How do I make an Android PWA open external links in the actual browser, not a Web view?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

This refers to external links (outside my domain) specifically, this isn't an issue with my manifest scope.

I have made my links `target="_blank" rel="noopener"`. My understanding from the limited documentation I've been able to find is that this should cause the actual user-set default browser to be invoked, but it does not. Instead it opens in an unconfigurable WebView over my app. (My test device is a Pixel on latest Android 14.)

How do I open the actual browser from a PWA? I am open to an actual config option or HTML attribute I can set, or failing that a weird hack.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be possible to make subsite with another manifest file which can redirect to browser (display:browser). Like you'd replace text of links to original but in the background it'd load a subsite to redirect to browser...
Like:
`<a href="subsite.html">https://link-you-want-to-redirect.html</a>` then blank subsite page with linked different manifest ( `display:"browser")`
Here more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it doesn't work - display: browser is the default, and a WebView seems to count as a browser here. There's not an option to force use of a true browser in this context.

Comment: Also using app URI's (eg. chrome:https...)

Answer (score 1):

I have a *partial* answer to this problem. You can encode Android intents as URLs from a browser, so you can check if you're in your PWA (via for example checking the user-agent for "Android" and `window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)')`) and then encode your links as follows:

```js
const url = new URL(link);
const scheme = url.protocol.replace(/:$/, "");
url.hash = `#Intent;scheme=${scheme};action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end`;
// This is necessary rather than setting url.protocol because you
// can't change the protocol on a URL object between "special" and
// "non-special" protocols. Don't ask.
return url.href.replace(/^[^:]+/, "intent");
```

This should, as far as I understand, trigger the link to be opened in the default browser. What *actually* happens is that it pops up a "choose activity" window offering me a choice between Chrome and any other browsers. I don't understand why; I don't see this chooser when following links from anywhere else, my default browser is set, and it doesn't offer to let me pick a default. Attempts to set the `package` in the intent and the like to force it to pick a known browser have also not worked.

If anybody knows how to modify this to actually just invoke the default browser I'd count that as a correct answer.